# System gave me an extra "Share Feedback" review but didn't share any feedback

Tags: bug, review

Earlier today, I completed [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/35470951) in the First Answers queue on Stack Overflow, choosing the "Share Feedback" option to add a "Community Bot comment." After I completed the review, I accidentally 'fat-fingered' the mouse pad on my PC and apparently clicked on the "Submit" button for the next answer presented for review.

Normally, this wouldn't do anything because that button is disabled until a recognized action has been taken or selected. However, in this case, the system added the [next post in the queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/35464562) to my review history, after giving that a "Share Feedback" verdict, too. But note that there is no actual feedback (bot comment) on that second post (and nor did I add a comment 'as myself' and then delete it – as any SO moderator will be able to confirm).

What I *have* noticed, though, is that the bot comment on the first review has an upvote from me (I see an orange up-arrow), and that isn't normally the case.

In this case, that second answer isn't especially problematical; however, had it been (say) spam or abusive, I may have inadvertently allowed it to pass the review had I not noticed my 'fat finger' action. Thus, I think this is a bug that should be addressed.